# Observable: Return the result of a Promise until unsubscribed

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I want to write a function that returns an Observable to subscribe to. The Observable should emit the result of the Promise every three seconds.

The following function returns the Promise, but i would like it to return the result of the Promise:

```
public static getWifiInfos(): Observable<Promise<ConnectionInfo>> {
    return Observable
        .interval(3000)
        .map(() => Hotspot.getConnectionInfo());
}
```

I am working with Angular and TypeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `switchMap`, which maps your interval to the output(s) of another Observable. I don't know how to describe it any better.

```
public static getWifiInfos(): Observable<ConnectionInfo> {
  return <Observable<ConnectionInfo>> Observable
    .interval(3000)
    .switchMap(() => 
      Observable.fromPromise(Hotspot.getConnectionInfo())
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try below,

```
   private connectionInfoSubject = new Subject<ConnectionInfo>();

   connectionInfoObservable = this.connectionInfoSubject.asObservable();

   public static getWifiInfos(): Observable<ConnectionInfo>{
       Observable
        .interval(3000)
        .map(() => {
            // Assuming Hotspot.getConnectionInfo is a synchronous call                
            this.connectionInfoSubject.next(Hotspot.getConnectionInfo());
           // If Hotspot.getConnectionInfo is promise
           Hotspot.getConnectionInfo().then(result => {
                this.connectionInfoSubject.next(result);
           })
        });
   }
```

Hope this helps!!